# Unable to pass output values from a Terraform module which uses a git source back to the caller

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a Terraform module which is used to build a GCP virtual machine.  The module is located at ../modules/vm/main.tf.  The problem I have is that inside of main, I also have a source setting which points to a github repo.  So when I call my ../modules/vm/main.tf module from my root main.tf module, I'm not able to capture to returns from the git source and pass them all the way back to my root main.tf.

So basically, ../modules/vm/main.tf's git source returns output, that output needs to be returned to ./main.tf.  I'm failing epically at this point and need some assistance.

Here is the main.tf in the root:

```
module "vm1" {
    source = ../modules/vm/main.tf
    
    vm.name = var.vm1name
    vm.size = var.vm1.size
}
```

Here is what is in the ../modules/vm/variables.tf file:

```
variable "name" {
    type = "string"
    description = "The name of the VM."
}

variable "size" {
    type = "string"
    description = "The instance size."
}
```

Here is what is in the main.tf file in ../modules/vm/main.tf

```
module "virtual_machine" {

    source = "git::https://github.myorg.com/repository?ref=v1.0"
    name = var.name
    size = var.size    
  
}
```

One of the output values of "git::[https://github.myorg.com/repository?ref=v1.0"](https://github.myorg.com/repository?ref=v1.0%22) is the IP address of the virtual machine.  It doesn't seem to be an issue with getting the output, but I need to send this output back to ./main.tf from ../modules/vm/main.tf because the next modules used in my root main.tf need the IP address assigned to the VM.  That's where I'm having the problem, I don't know exactly how to get that returned IP address into my outputs.tf file to return to my root main.tf.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hello in order to better understand your issue, it would be really helpfull to add the code to the question and if possible also the error code

Comment: Just updated the question with the relevant code.  Shortened for brevity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an `outputs.tf` file in your module

Path: `../modules/vm/outputs.tf`

Assuming that the exported variable for the ip address of the *https://github.myorg.com/repository?ref=v1.0* module is named `ip_address`

```
output "ip_addres" {
 description = "Ip address of VM"
 value       = module.virtual_machine.ip_address
}
```

Then in your `main.tf` you can refer to the ip address

```
module.vm1.ip_address
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was the direction I was trying to go but my syntax was wrong, this clarifies it so much for me as to what I messed up.  I'll update if it works or bombs :)  Thank you again so very much!

Comment: Glad to be of help. If it fails dont hesitate to provide feedback ;). And if it succeds, an accepted answer would be highly appreciated